# AJAX load doesn't run javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I have a main page with a graph on, a dropdown box allows the user to select which graph they want to see.

When the dropdown gets changed I want AJAX to load the correct graph from my file, graphmaker.php. This file has all the graphs in appropriate DIVs, i.e graph1, graph2 etc.

These graphs are generated using Google Charts Visualisation.

However, when I do this AJAX just loads an empty box and from what I have researched this is because the script on the page doesn't get executed.

In essence, I want Ajax to:

- get graphmaker.php
- render the page
- then pull out the correct graph

My code:

```
function switchgraph(graph) {
var switchto = $("#graph"+graph+"_dd").val();
$('#graph'+graph).load('graphmaker.php #'+switchto);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Dave

Comment: Stick all the stuff you want to do in a function and run that function in the callback that load() provides.

Comment: I think you just cannot do that. It would require to have some kind of a sandbox for the graphmaker.php where the page would render and the Javascript (related to that page) could run. I think the only thing you can do is to include the Google Charts Visualisation into your current page and "call" it after you added the DIV content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a selector with `load`, [which removes the scripts](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution), select the relevant graph once the AJAX call has finished:

```
function switchgraph(graph) {
    var switchto = $("#graph"+graph+"_dd").val();
    $('#graph'+graph).load('graphmaker.php', function onComplete() {
       function doMoveGraph() {
           $('#graph' + graph).empty().append(toBeUsed);
       }
       function checkMoveGraph() {
            if (!toBeUsed.is(":empty")) {
                doMoveGraph();
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkMoveGraph, 100);
            }
       }
       var toBeUsed = $(this).find('#'+switchto);
       setTimeout(checkMoveGraph, 100);
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more about the timeoutloop/event handler - this may need to be spoon fed, apologies! This looks like it'll work though, yay :)

Comment: It depends on the result of the scripts. Do they set the src attribute of an image tag? Or write to a canvas? Or...? Do they perhaps fire an event? You would somehow need to deduce that the script has 'finished', and how you do that obviously depends on what the script does. Adding a link to some live code in your question would help with this.

Comment: OK - here is a copy of graphmaker.php (http://pastebin.com/bMQgCmjx). What are your thoughts? Unfortunately I can't provide a live link as the code is running behind a login - apologies.

Comment: Hmm, in this case, it would actually probably make more sense to load only the data via AJAX, and then generate the graphs in your main page. So you could make the php return a JSON structure with the graph data (the data you currently pass to the `addRows` API). Then you could use that to generate the right graph yourself from the main page.

Comment: I've added the timeout loop code anyway, although I still recommend you use JSON only for the data, and create the graphs in the main page. In any case, the timeout loop works by checking if the element containing the graph is still empty. If it's not, it moves the element to the container you specified. Note that the resulting DOM events might affect the graph API's functioning... I'm not familiar enough with the graph API to tell (another reason to use pure JSON for the data, and create the graphs from the main page, really).

Comment: Hmm, that sounds too complicated for me! I'm not a JS whizz at all, at the moment I've achieved what I need using an iframe and a PHP switch to display the graph that is selected through graphmaker.php?g=1,2,3,etc. Obviously this isn't really what I want so I may have to come back to this. Any help would be hugely appreciated here, thanks @Gijs!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
$.getScript()
```

Or You can try

```
$.ajax({
 url: url,
 dataType: "script",
 success: success
});
```

Please check the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $.ajax I suggest you using $.post function, so try something like this:

```
$.post('graphmaker.php', { data : dataSource },
  function(data) {
    //On Success
  }
)
```